# I am trying to deploy a web-app on google app scripts to connect to one of my telegram bots. However I just cant receive initDataUnsafe/initData

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, telegram-bot

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Telegram Web App</title>
    

    <script>
      // initialize the button
      const mainButton = window.Telegram.WebApp.MainButton;
      mainButton.text = "Save Preferences";
      mainButton.enable();
      mainButton.show();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="username", type="text">
    <p id="test">
      This page is a simple webapp integrated with telegram bot 
    </p>
    <script>
      const initDataUnsafe = window.Telegram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe;
      if (Object.keys(initDataUnsafe).length === 0 || typeof initDataUnsafe.user === 'undefined') {
        google.script.run.asd(("shit gone wrong"));
      }
      google.script.run.asd((initDataUnsafe));
      const initData = window.Telegram.WebApp.initData;
      google.script.run.asd(initData);

      var tg = JSON.stringify(window.Telegram.WebApp);
      google.script.run.asd(tg);
      google.script.run.asd(tg.initData);
      google.script.run.asd(tg.initDataUnsafe);
      google.script.run.asd(tg.version);
      google.script.run.asd(tg.platform);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above is the html code for my web-app. The script 'asd' is just a code that appendRow to a spreadsheet for me to debug. Where did I go wrong? I am launching the web-app from the menu-button. I have also tried sendMessage -> inline_keyboard to no avail.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!